# The difference between total error, prediction error and fitted error via residual

Tags: regression, estimation, residuals, error

Consider a regression model $Y=E(Y|X)+Prediction \ Error$ i.e $Prediction \ error = Y-E(Y|X)$. Now, define an estimate of the regression function $E(Y|X)=\hat{Y}+ Fitted \ error$ i.e. Fitted error = $E(Y|X)-\hat{Y}$. Further, define residual = $Y-\hat{Y}$. Now, we have $Total \ error = Residual 
 \ error + Fitted \ error$.

Therefore, the total error can be expressed as $Total \ error = Prediction \ error + 2 \times Fitted 
 \ error$.

Is the above derivation regarding errors, is right or wrong?

Comment: Where did your $2$ come from?

Comment: 1. Prediction error = Tru vale of response - predicted valeu of the response = True value of response - (estimated value of the prediction i.e. fitted value of y + fitted error) = True value - fitted value of y - fitted error => prediction error = residual - fitted error => residual = prediction error + fitted error.

2. Total error = residual error + fitted error => residual error = total error - fitted error.
3. From (1) and (2) total error = prediction error + 2 fitted error.

Comment: I would have thought *total error* is in fact $Y - \hat Y$ (what you call *residual error*). This is $(Y- E[Y \mid X]) +(E[Y \mid X] - \hat Y)$ so the sum of what you call *prediction error* and *fitted error*.